# Use FineUploader with Typescript (Angular2 project)

Tags: angular, typescript, fine-uploader

I'm facing a problem to use fineuploader library to my angular2 project. I Don't find a way to implement it without using fineuploader.js directly in the index html file. Is there an example of implementation for Typescript? Thank u

```
***Gulpfile***


    gulp.task('restore:fine-uploader', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/fine-uploader/**/*.*'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(libs + 'fine-uploader'));
    });

    gulp.task('restore',
    [
    'restore:core-js',
    'restore:zone.js',
    'restore:reflect-metadata',
    'restore:systemjs',
    'restore:rxjs',
    'restore:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    'restore:angular',
    'restore:bootstrap',
    'restore:ng2-pagination',
    'restore:fine-uploader'
    ]);

***Systemjs.js***

    (function (global) {
    System.config({
        baseURL: "/",
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': './libs/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic':
                'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'ng2-pagination': 'npm:ng2-pagination',
            'fine-uploader': 'npm:fine-uploader',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            fineUploader: {
                main: 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader.min',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
}
    });
})(this);
```

****upload.component.ts****

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FineUploader } from 'fineUploader';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-upload',
    templateUrl: './app/upload/upload.component.html'
})
export class UploadComponent {

}
```

Comment: which lib/plugin you are using ?

Comment: I'm using FineUploader (http://fineuploader.com/) and I want to implement it in an angular2/Typescript project, but i didn't found any example

Comment: You can read and https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/pull/1689 for updates on the effort to create and bundle a TS definition file with a released version of Fine Uploader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I've understand. Fine-Uploader is a JS library with no Typescript files which we can use. WE CAN'T Import directly the library to our TS file. The solution is to declare a fine-uploader object like `declare var qq:any;` which we can use in our export class.

Comment: ts of fineUploader is aveilable at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/8d4c621ffc147d6c91fbcd68ba94482b94665078/typescript/fine-uploader.d.ts

Comment: Do u know if it's an official release? ty

Comment: no & `no need` cause it is definition file you can write your own.

Comment: I've tried to import it into my typscript file but module cannot find ... how can I import this .d.ts file?

Comment: thank you. I'm using "declare var qq:any" and manage my object like Fine-Uplaoder say to do in their docs

Answer (score 2):

Using `declare var qq:any;` is not the right way of doing it. This is what I did to make it work:

**Step Zero:** Include the CSS and JS file in the `angular-cli.json` file.

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader-gallery.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.min.js"
],
```

**Step One:**
Add `/// <reference types="fine-uploader" />` on top of your component file.

**Step Two:** Declare following variables:

```
uploader: FineUploader.qq;
uiOptions: FineUploader.UIOptions;
coreEvents: FineUploader.CoreEvents;
```

**Step Three:**
Add UI options and initialise FineUploader in `ngOnInit`

```
this.uiOptions = {
    element: document.getElementById('qq-template'),
    template: "qq-template"
};
this.uploader = new qq.FineUploader(this.uiOptions);
```

**Step Four:**
Add the template HTML in your `COMPONENT_NAME.component.html` file. You may find the HTML in `node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/templates/`

Comment: Everything works well till **Step Three** but at **Step Four** we cannot add templates given by fine-uploader. It uses `<script type="text/template">` tag and further angular strips that tag from COMPONENT_NAME.component.html

Answer (score 0):

add following in systemjs.config

```
'fineUploader': 'npm:fine-uploader'
```

and

```
fineUploader: {
    main: '/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.min',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
```

in component add

```
import {FineUploader} from 'fineUploader';
```

for more you can add `fine-uploader.d.ts`
find at 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/8d4c621ffc147d6c91fbcd68ba94482b94665078/typescript/fine-uploader.d.ts

Comment: That's what I've done 

import { FineUploader } from 'fineUploader'; 

but it cannot find the module !

I've installed FineUploader via npm install fineuploader, and with gulpfile I put the library in my /lib folder to use it. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I cannot find the module simply because no ts file is found into FineUploader folder ... Is fine-uploader works with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

**Official solution can be found on [Fine Uploader page](https://docs.fineuploader.com/features/modules.html).**

You just need to install the Fine Uploader via npm and initialize in your typescript file like this (for UI mode and traditional endpoints):

```
import { FineUploader } from 'fine-uploader';

let uploader = new FineUploader({...})
```

Note that Fine Uploader template doesn't have to be in `<script>` tags in index.html file. Adding a template inside `<div hidden>` tag with a specific id in any component would be enough.